# JQuery validation form is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have created this HTML form that uses jQuery validation. However, I haven't found any validation alert yet.

This is my Javascript code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    // Initialise le form
    $("#faq-form").validate({
        // Spécifier les réglements de validation 
        rules: {
            message:"required",
            adresse_mail:"required",
            slider:"required",
            radio-choice:"required",
            flip: "required"
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            message: "Votre question n'est pas validé",
            adresse_mail: "Votre est adresse mail n'est pas valide",
            slider: "votre age n'est pas rempli!",
            radio-choice: "Quel est votre sexe?",
            flip:"Est-ce-que vous communiquez LCF" 
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

  });

</script>
```

This is my html form: I have named and identified all the fields correctly. But I don't know why i coundn't see any validation alert message.

```
<form action="traitement_formulaire2.php" method="POST" id="faq-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="hidden" name="site" id="site" value="sis" required />
    <input type="email" name="adresse_mail" id="adresse_mail" />
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="18" min="1" max="99" data-theme="c" />
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Sexe<sup>*</sup></legend>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice" value="Homme" class="required">
        Homme<br />
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice" value="Femme">
        Femme
    </fieldset>

    <select name="flip-10" id="flip" data-role="slider" data-theme="c">
        <option value="off">Non</option>
        <option value="on">Oui</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Valider</button>
</form>
```

Anyone can help me to find out my mistakes?

Comment: Before HTML! let me check that now

Comment: @HowardRenollet He is using `DOMContentLoaded` event not IIFE.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - I missed the `$`... my bad :)

Comment: I have placed the JS code after HTML, it's not working

Comment: Please change <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice" value="Homme" class="required"> to <input type="radio" name="radio_choice" value="Homme" class="required"> and change from javascript rules and messages also

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax errors in your code. You can't use `blah-blah` property names without quotes. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/nddv8L1z/).

```
    rules: {
        message:"required",
        adresse_mail:"required",
        slider:"required",
        "radio-choice":"required", //notice ""
        flip: "required"
    },
```

Comment: Yes.  Everyone see:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)

Answer (score 1):

Please change the name radio-choice to radio_choice or if you want to keep the name same then wrap up the name with quote in the js part like "radio-choice"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


        <script>
            $(function() {
                // Initialise le form
                $("#faq-form").validate({
                    // Spécifier les réglements de validation 
                    rules: {
                        message: "required",
                        adresse_mail: "required",
                        slider: "required",
                        radio_choice: "required",
                        flip: "required"
                    },
                    // Specify the validation error messages
                    messages: {
                        message: "Votre question n'est pas validé",
                        adresse_mail: "Votre est adresse mail n'est pas valide",
                        slider: "votre age n'est pas rempli!",
                        radio_choice: "Quel est votre sexe?",
                        flip: "Est-ce-que vous communiquez LCF"
                    },
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                        form.submit();
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="traitement_formulaire2.php" method="POST" id="faq-form" novalidate="novalidate">
            <input type="hidden" name="site" id="site" value="sis" required/>
            <input type="email" name="adresse_mail" id="adresse_mail" />
            <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="18" min="1" max="99" data-theme="c" />
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <legend>Sexe<sup>*</sup></legend>
                <input type="radio" name="radio_choice" value="Homme" class="required"> Homme<br />
                <input type="radio" name="radio_choice"  value="Femme"> Femme
            </fieldset>

            <select name="flip-10" id="flip" data-role="slider" data-theme="c">
                <option value="off">Non</option>
                <option value="on">Oui</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Valider</button>

        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He would not have to change any of the names.  Just use quotations.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)

Comment: Well then he should wrap up the name with quote like "radio-choice"

Comment: @FarukOmar : Hello Sir, i have a final problem with the slider. this is my validation rule "slider:{required:true,rangelength:[18, 99]}". But still the field show error message "not valid". How to fix it?

Comment: You should use range: [18, 99] instead of rangelength:[18, 99] . rangelength actually validate string length like: 'abcd' equal 4

Answer (score 0):

You can't use '-' for the properties names, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kk9qge9b/

```
<form action="traitement_formulaire2.php" method="POST" id="faq-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="hidden" name="site" id="site" value="sis" required />
    <input type="email" name="adresse_mail" id="adresse_mail" />
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="18" min="1" max="99" data-theme="c" />
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Sexe<sup>*</sup></legend>
        <input type="radio" name="radiochoice" id="radiochoice" value="Homme" class="required">
        Homme<br />
        <input type="radio" name="radiochoice" id="radiochoice" value="Femme">
        Femme
    </fieldset>

    <select name="flip-10" id="flip" data-role="slider" data-theme="c">
        <option value="off">Non</option>
        <option value="on">Oui</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Valider</button>
</form>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialise le form
    $("#faq-form").validate({
        // Spécifier les réglements de validation 
        rules: {
            message:"required",
            adresse_mail:"required",
            slider:"required",
            radiochoice:"required",
            flip: "required"
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            message: "Votre question n'est pas validé",
            adresse_mail: "Votre est adresse mail n'est pas valide",
            slider: "votre age n'est pas rempli!",
            radiochoice: "Quel est votre sexe?",
            flip:"Est-ce-que vous communiquez LCF" 
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

  });
```